# Wrapping a table row in a element (hyperlink) in HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, anchor

I'm trying to wrap a table row in an "a" element (hyperlink) in order to make the whole row clickable. I'm using the HTML5 doctype, which should allow for this sort of thing and in fact I've had no problem wrapping other block-level elements in links. In fact, wrapping an a element around a whole table seems to work.

Markup as follows:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
      <a href="#">
          <tr>
              <td>25 Nov 2010</td>
              <td>Active</td>
          </tr>
      </a>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wrapping HTML table rows in <a> tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10245279/wrapping-html-table-rows-in-a-tags)

Answer (score 7):

From the [HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#the-tr-element):

Contexts in which element `tr` can be used:

- As a child of a thead element.
- As a child of a tbody element.
- As a child of a tfoot element.
- As a child of a table element, after any caption, colgroup, and thead elements, but only if there are no tbody elements that are children of the table element.

That means you cannot inherit `tr` in `a` element.
In your case I would go with Javascript onclick instead. Alternatively, you can put the same anchor element in each of the rows `td`s.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ah, thanks much! Sadly wrapping a <td> in a hyperlink doesn't seem to work either (just as well, not the tidiest solution). Back to jQuery it is it seems!

Comment: I didnt say wrap the `td` but rather put an anchor inside the `td` and adjust the size to cover the whole space. `<td><a href="#" >Content of td</a></td>`

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `display: table-*` CSS? It's [widely supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-table) and is fairly seamless:

HTML:

```
<div class="table">
    <div class="tbody">
      <a href="#" class="tr">
          <div class="td">25 Nov 2010</div>
          <div class="td">Active</div>
      </a>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.table { display: table; }
.tbody { display: table-row-group; }
.tr { display: table-row; }
.td { display: table-cell; }
```

[See codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EjdaBL)

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the `tr` with an `a` element.  Just set the `a` to `display:table-row`