# Wrapping HTML table rows in <a> tags

Tags: html, html-table

Is it possible to wrap entire table rows in `<a>` tags? I want the the entire row to be a clickable link.

If I try the following, the links get rendered above and outside the table:

**This:**

```
<table>
<a href="value_url"><tr><td>value</td><td>value</td></tr></a>
<a href="value_url"><tr><td>value</td><td>value</td></tr></a>
</table>
```

**Renders like this:**

```
<a href="value_url"></a>
<a href="value_url"></a>
<table>
<tr><td>value</td><td>value</td></tr>
<tr><td>value</td><td>value</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It would be quite nice to mention HTML version

Comment: You can check [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4369206/wrapping-a-table-row-in-a-element-hyperlink-in-html5) question

Answer (score 47, accepted):

*Edit 2021:*
It seems nowadays there's better options that are more semantic and more screen-reader-friendly. Check out e.g. [Jans solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61589399/540725).

*Original answer:*
as a link in each td is not a good alternative and using js is a bit dirty, here is another html/css approach:

HTML:

```
<div class="table">
    <a class="table-row" href="/mylink">
        <div class="table-cell">...</div>
        <div class="table-cell">...</div>
        <div class="table-cell">...</div>
    </a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.table { display:table; }
.table-row { display:table-row; }
.table-cell { display:table-cell; }
```

Comment: This is not a good approach. This is not semantic and will not work nicely with screen readers.

Comment: You could explore the use of aria-role to make it more accessible to screen readers.

Comment: What if I'm using html for mailing? :D

Comment: In Mails you definitely can't use JS, and I think many clients need to have the styles inline (style="" in each html tag)
If this solution still doesn't work, you could give a try to use divs with fix widths and float, but I can't guarantee it works, html support in mail clients is a real pain actually

Comment: This solution breaks the web. Only use if you have no care for accessibility or usability.

Comment: If your're using Bootstrap 4 these are builtin as helper classes : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/#notation

Answer (score 38):

It renders like that because the browser is respecting the W3C specification and only allowing `<tr>` tags as direct descendents of `<table>`.

As a solution, you could either put an `<a>` tag inside *each* `<td>` that points to the same URL:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="http://url/stuff">
                First column
            </a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="http://url/stuff">
                Second column
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Or you could bind an `onClick` handler to the `<tr>` with JavaScript. A jQuery example would be this:

```
$('table tr').click(function() {
    window.location = 'http://location/here';
});
```

Or, even better, use delegated events (jQuery 1.7+):

```
$('table').on('click', 'tr', function() {
    window.location = 'http://location/here';
});
```

Comment: Thanks for laying out all possible solutions

Comment: We used the Javascript version once and regretted it. Users can't Ctrl-click or Shift-click to open in new tab/window. Worth noting that; it might even be desirable in your app/site.

Comment: @BernhardHofmann it is possible to catch the `event` on click and test for `event.metaKey` or `event.ctrlKey`, but I agree, it isn't quite ideal as sometimes it may be blocked by popup blockers. http://stackoverflow.com/a/2445640/436014

Comment: @waffl And then it still doesn't work for middle click (which I use extensively). Or right click -> open in new tab. Also, no browser link target preview on hover. JS links are always a pain :(

Answer (score 20):

Another simple, CSS only solution is turning `<a>` into block elements

```
<tr>
  <td><a href="#">name 1</a></td><td><a href="#">link 1</a></td>    
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><a href="#">name 2</a></td><td><a href="#">link 2</a></td>    
</tr>
```

The CSS would be:

```
td > a {
  display: block;
}
```

Then the `<a>` would take up the entire `<td>`, and making entire row clickable without JS if the link is repeated for each cell in a row.

https://jsfiddle.net/evwa451n/

Comment: Great idea. Using padding on the cells reintroduces non-clickable gaps, so put a equal -ve margins on the `td > a` rule to close up the gap again, then reapply the padding on the `td > a` rule.

Comment: @IanGoldby What is a "-ve margins"?

Comment: @ChuckD exactly what it says. Set the margin to a negative amount equal to the padding, e.g. padding 4px and margin: -4px

Comment: As soon as any of the text wraps, this no longer works properly as the anchor doesn't fill the cell: https://jsfiddle.net/950c1284/.  This works however: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3966027/make-link-in-table-cell-fill-the-entire-row-height#15801081.

Answer (score 11):

It's invalid HTML to have any elements other than `thead`,`tbody` or `tfoot` as a direct child of a `table`, and those elements have only `tr` as *their* valid children.

Any other content must be inside of a `td` or `th` to be valid.

What you're seeing is the browser restructuring your DOM so that it's as valid as it can be. The problem with relying on that behaviour though is that different browsers react in different ways.

If you need a `tr` to be interactive (and for clicks on those elements to lead somewhere/do something) you should use JavaScript.

But, short answer, yes you *can* do it, but it's not valid to do so, so please don't.

For interactive table rows, though, one solution (in plain JavaScript):

```
var rows = document.getElementsByTagName('tr'),
    url;

for (var i=0,len=rows.length; i<len; i++){
    rows[i].onclick = function(){
        uri = this.getAttribute('data-url');
        window.location = uri;
    };
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/LaDEz/).

(Which, obviously, requires that the `tr` elements have a `data-url` attribute to specify where they should link to.)

Comment: Much better to add one click handler on the table itself and use event delegation and the target to find out which row was clicked.

Answer (score 7):

**New and even better solution using [CSS Subgrids](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_grid_layout/Subgrid) (I'm excited):**

We can now use Subgrids for our table rows. This way we can also add hover states or paddings to the individual rows.

```html
<style>
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(0, auto)); /* Auto sizing columns */
}
.grid-row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: subgrid; /* New feature, makes row inherit parents grid */
  grid-column: 1 / -1; /* make row span full grid */
}
</style>

<div class="grid">
  <div>Header column 1</div>
  <div>Header column 2 (Any content size works)</div>
  <div>Header column 3</div>
  <a href="https://example.com" class="grid-row">
    <div>Every column adjusts dynamically</div>
    <div>Content 2</div>
    <div>Content 3</div>
  </a>
  <a href="https://example.com" class="grid-row">
    <div>Content 1</div>
    <div>Content 2</div>
    <div>Content 3</div>
  </a>
  <a href="https://example.com" class="grid-row">
    <div>Content 1</div>
    <div>Works like a table!</div>
    <div>Content 3</div>
  </a>
</div>
```

**New and fancy solution:** It is funny that in 2021 there is still no clean solution for table rows with links - I advice you to use display grid instead. Using `repeat(YOUR_COLUMN_COUNT, minmax(0, auto))` for `grid-template-columns` achieves a grid to behave really similar to a table - you get auto sizing and adjusting columns. In addition you can use anchor tags and even create a sticky header without going insane:

```html
<div style="display: grid; grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(0, auto));">
  <div>Header column 1</div>
  <div>Header column 2 (Any content size works)</div>
  <div>Header column 3</div>
  <a href="https://example.com" style="display: contents;">
    <div>Every column adjusts dynamically</div>
    <div>Content 2</div>
    <div>Content 3</div>
  </a>
  <a href="https://example.com" style="display: contents;">
    <div>Content 1</div>
    <div>Content 2</div>
    <div>Content 3</div>
  </a>
  <a href="https://example.com" style="display: contents;">
    <div>Content 1</div>
    <div>Works like a table!</div>
    <div>Content 3</div>
  </a>
</div>
```

**Update:** Unfortunately the original solution below does not work unless the table rows are dynamically inserted with javascript (see example below). Browsers skip the syntax check when new elements are inserted via javascript, so that way it is possible to get the anchor tags to stay in the table and prevent the browser from moving them outside.

```js
let tbody = document.getElementById("myTBody");

for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  let anchor = document.createElement("a");

  anchor.setAttribute("style", "display: contents;");
  anchor.setAttribute("href", "https://example.com");

  let row = document.createElement("tr");

  let col1 = document.createElement("td");
  let col2 = document.createElement("td");
  col1.append(document.createTextNode("Column 1"));
  col2.append(document.createTextNode("My longer Column 2"));

  row.appendChild(col1);
  row.appendChild(col2);

  anchor.appendChild(row);
  tbody.appendChild(anchor);
}
```

```html
<p>This table doesnt work with anchors around the rows:</p>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th>Column 2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <a href="https://example.com" style="display: contents !important;">
      <tr>
        <td>Column 1</td>
        <td>My longer Column 2</td>
      </tr>
    </a>
    <a href="https://example.com" style="display: contents !important">
      <tr>
        <td>Column 1</td>
        <td>Column 2</td>
      </tr>
    </a>
  </tbody>
</table>
<p>This table does work with anchors around the rows:</p>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th>Column 2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="myTBody">
    <!-- Rows get inserted by javascript -->
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Original:** You could also use `display: contents;`. This causes the a tags childs to behave like they are a child of the a tags parent.

In your HTML:

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th>Column 2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <a href="https://example.com" style="display: contents;">
      <tr>
        <td>Column 1</td>
        <td>Column 2</td>
      </tr>
    </a>
    <a href="https://example.com" style="display: contents;">
      <tr>
        <td>Column 1</td>
        <td>Column 2</td>
      </tr>
    </a>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Support in different browsers should be enough most of the times (see https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-display-contents).

Comment: I think this is the best non-javascript solution; however, beware that the anchor tag is NOT included in the accessibility tree [this is a current bug in most browsers, it should be included] (see MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display#display_contents)

Comment: I don't get why this is upvoted? This does not work in any browsers i've tried, Chrome, Firefox or Safari?

Comment: @lowkey is actually right. I just tried the code in a standalone html file and it does not work. The browser just moves the anchor tags outside of the table. **Whats strange here** - In my vue projects the markup stays like written in the file and the anchor tags do not move out of the table. So when using vue the markup above works perfectly fine. Does anyone have an idea whats going on here?

Comment: I updated my answer to address the originally provided wrong answer and suggested a really nice alternative way to html tables (imo).

Answer (score 6):

You could use onclick, so you can get the content dynamically

```
<td onclick="window.location='http://www.google.com';" style='cursor: pointer;'>Hello</td>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ankJw/

Comment: The only change you need to make to this is to have the `onClick` handler in the `<tr>`, instead of the `<td>`; the OP wants to make an entire table row clickable.

Answer (score 3):

Why you don't want to make click event on `tr` ? It's not possible to have anchor tag like you want so you can make click event and add aditional CSS for making it to look like anchor.

**Jquery:**

```
$("table tr").click(function() {
    window.location = "http://www.google.com/";
});
```

Comment: Apparently i have to- but you always look for the non-js solution first

Comment: Because you don't know where you are going (hover and see url, like in an anchor tag), you can't right click and copy url, you cant open in a new tab, etc...

Answer (score 2):

Just in additional to others I have to add that I personnaly prefer to do like this

```
<tr onclick="window.location='http://www.google.com';" >
  <td>Text...</td>
</tr>
```

in case of **ASP.NET MVC** do it like

```
<tr onclick="window.location = '@Url.RouteUrl("Product", new { SeName = @product.SeName })';">
```

Answer (score 2):

The solutions provided here helped me, but I don't think that using window.location is a good approach because user cannot do ctrl+click, open in another tab, or see where the url is going to. I'm building this page and I like to see the url built without clicking it, and chrome shows this on hover. I could not get over this, so I decided to use @Bojangles suggestion above to wrap each td with a link.

First, add the data-href to each tr, as others suggested.

Then, wrap each td in a link via js:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        //wrap each td's contents with a hyperlink targeting the data-href 
        $('*[data-href]').children("td").wrapInner(function () {
            return "<a href='" + this.parentElement.attributes["data-href"].value + "'></a>";
        });
    });
```

optionally, use css to make the hyperlink use up all of the cell

```
    table tr a {
        display:block; /*the link occupies the whole cell, so it's all clickable*/
    }
```