# Table: how to change pictures on mouseover on single rows?

Tags: html, css, html-table, mouseevent, mouseover

I'm working on a website and I've to create a table with a mouse over effect the effect is only when you go with the mouse on the picture and only on the PDF icon.

What I need now is to apply this effect when you go with the mouse on the single table rows. How can I do it?

HTML:

```
<td class="thumbnail-item" data-th="PDF"><a href="http://salmenpark-test.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/QH001_LadenMIETEN_SalmenparkBusiness.pdf" target="_blank"><img src="http://salmenpark-test.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/pdf.png" alt="PDF" height="24" width="24"> </a>
      <div class="tooltip">
        <img src="qh_1.png" alt="" width="570" height="403" />
        <span class="overlay"></span>
        
        <span class="overlay"></span>
    </div></td>
```

CSS :

```
  .thumbnail-item {
/* position relative so that we can use position absolute for the    tooltip */
display: inherit;
height: 10px;
max-width: 5px;

}

.thumbnail-item a {
display: block;
}

.tooltip {
/* by default, hide it */
display: none;
/* allow us to move the tooltip */
position: absolute;
/* align the image properly */
padding: 8px 0 0 8px;
z-index: 500;
top: 7px;
left: -8px !important;
max-width: 570px !important;
max-height: 403px !important;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antionio:

CSS:

```
.thumbnail-item {
/* delete the line that was here for inheriting the display * / 
height: 10px;
max-width: 5px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<tr class="thumbnail-item white">...</tr>
<tr class="thumbnail-item grey">...</tr>
```

etc, etc.

You were adding the "thumbnail-item" css reference to the `<td>`tag which represents a cell of data. You want the "thumbnail-item" css reference to be on the entire row, so it should be on each `<tr>` tag instead.

Comment: works perfectly! ther's the option to add a <a href="#"> to the rows?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10245279/wrapping-html-table-rows-in-a-tags[/link] --- I like the answer by David Thomas --- Essentially, no you can not/should not use `<a>` tags before the `<td>` is declared. Jscript though solves this easily using onClick.

Answer (score 0):

In your Jquery code, use the class of your td.hover function and try with the below code.

```
$(".thumbnail-item").hover(function() {
   //Write your js code what you have written for hover pdf image
});
```

It would be better for us to understand if you post your jquery code as well.