# Laravel a tag not visible

Tags: php, html, laravel

I've got this code:

```
 <div class="container col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <div class="well well bs-component">
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Logo</th>
                        <th>Bedrijfsnaam</th>
                        <th>Plaats</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                @foreach($companies as $company)
                    <a href="/bedrijf/{!! $company->CompanyId !!}">
                        <tr>
                                <td><img class="img-circle-company" src="{!! $company->Logo != null ? '/files/images/companylogos/'.$company->Logo : '/files/images/companylogos/default.png'!!}"/></td>
                                <td>{{ $company->CompanyName }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $company->City }}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </a>
                @endforeach
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
```

But the a tag is not working why is that? In my page source it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: you're wrapping a TR in the tag, which is not valid HTML so your browser might be stripping this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10245279/wrapping-html-table-rows-in-a-tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately wrapping `<tr>` elements in an anchor isn't valid HTML. Some browsers may not blink an eye at it, but most with remove the offending element. If you want to continue using tables, another option would be to add the anchor inside each `<td>` element.

```
 <div class="container col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
     <div class="well well bs-component">
         <table class="table">
             <thead>
                 <tr>
                     <th>Logo</th>
                     <th>Bedrijfsnaam</th>
                     <th>Plaats</th>
                 </tr>
             </thead>
             <tbody>
             @foreach($companies as $company)
                 <tr>
                     <td>
                         <a href="/bedrijf/{!! $company->CompanyId !!}">                        
                             <img class="img-circle-company" src="{!! $company->Logo != null ? '/files/images/companylogos/'.$company->Logo : '/files/images/companylogos/default.png'!!}"/>
                         </a>
                     </td>
                     <td><a href="/bedrijf/{!! $company->CompanyId !!}">{{ $company->CompanyName }}</td>
                     <td><a href="/bedrijf/{!! $company->CompanyId !!}">{{ $company->City }}</a></td>
                 </tr>
             @endforeach
             </tbody>
         </table>
     </div>
 </div>
```