# Directing page and making table row clickable inside php

Tags: php, html

I would like to know how to make a table row clickable and for it to direct to other page.

```
    <?php
      while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        echo
        "<tr>
          <td>{$row['id']}</td>
          <td>{$row['fname']} {$row['lname']}</td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>\n";

    ?>
```

I looked for other answers here at stack, and I tried the OnClick but it doesn't work and i get errors. Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the html anchor tag

```
 <?php
          while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            echo
            "<tr>
              <td>{$row['id']}</td>
              <td>{$row['fname']} {$row['lname']}<a href="your_direction" style="display: block"></a></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>\n";
    ?>
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'student_form' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\SHS REGISTRATION\admin.php on line 59"  im getting this syntax error when i insert that code @Johannes

Comment: can you give me your line 59 in admin.php then pls?

Comment: <td>{$row['id']}<a href="student_form.php" style="display: block"></a></td>  @Johannes

Comment: ahh i see use ' instead of " 
<td>{$row['id']}<a href='student_form.php' style='display: block;'></a></td>

Comment: thanks it worked~! i have last question, is it possible to make the  whole table row clickable? or the {$row['id']} clickable? @Johannes

Comment: You're welcome 

<div class="table">
    <a class="table-row" href="/mylink">
        <div class="table-cell">...</div>
        <div class="table-cell">...</div>
        <div class="table-cell">...</div>
    </a>
</div>

only if you do it like this because everything else is not rly clean code. You would have to style those divs like this: 

.table { display:table; }
.table-row { display:table-row; }
.table-cell { display:table-cell; }

or look it up http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10245279/wrapping-html-table-rows-in-a-tags

Comment: If i did help you, then i would like you to honor my effort with some upvotes thank you.

Comment: yes, you did @Johannes thank you again. i upvoted it :)