# Use Html.ActionLink on entire table row

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an `@Html.ActionLink` within my `<td>` element on my table which works fine

When I move the link to the `<tr>`, it does not work

Is this approach permitted against the entire row? I am trying to make the entire row clickable to run the action rather than the column

My code is

```
@foreach (var member in @Model.Memberships)
{
    <tr>
       ---> TRYING TO RUN THIS HERE -- @Html.ActionLink("Switch", "SwitchMembership", "HomePageSurface", new { membershipNumber = member.MembershipNumber, schemeType = member.SchemeType, memberStatusType = member.MemberStatusType, scheme = member.Scheme, returnUrl = Request.Url.AbsolutePath })
        @if (member.Selected)
        {
            <td class="visible-xs"><span class="user-management-current"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></span></td>
        }
        else
        {
            <td class="visible-xs">@Html.ActionLink("Switch", "SwitchMembership", "HomePageSurface", new { membershipNumber = member.MembershipNumber, schemeType = member.SchemeType, memberStatusType = member.MemberStatusType, scheme = member.Scheme, returnUrl = Request.Url.AbsolutePath }, new { @class = "icon-arrow-right" })</td>
        }
        ...
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: That isn't valid HTML, to make a `tr` clickable, you need to use Javascript. For example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17147821/how-to-make-a-whole-row-in-a-table-clickable-as-a-link

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wrapping HTML table rows in <a> tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10245279/wrapping-html-table-rows-in-a-tags)