# Vuetify table styles broken when adding a tag in tr

Tags: html, css, vuetify.js

I wanted to make my table rows link into some other pages and I don't wanna use the `@click:row` by default because it removes the open in a new tab in `contextmenu`. so I used the `v-slot:item` to manipulate my rows and adding `a` tag.

I added it successfully but the problem is that it breaks the default Vuetify styles! After adding `display: contents` (I found this solution from [Wrapping HTML table rows in  tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10245279/wrapping-html-table-rows-in-a-tags)) it was better but it won't be like the other tables.

My table looks likes this when there's an `a` tag:
[image]
(there's no border and other stuff)

The default look is like this:
[image]

My Codes looks like this:

```html
<template v-slot:item="{ item }">
  <tr>
    <a href="" style="display: contents; color: #212121">
      <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.ownerName }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.cartNumber }}</td>
      <td>IR-{{ item.shabaNumber }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.accountNumber }}</td>
      <td>
        <v-btn
          fab
          x-small
          text
          class="px-0 ml-2"
          color="#F40F02"
          @click.stop="deleteItem(item.id)"
        >
          <v-icon color="#F40F02">mdi-delete</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
      </td>
    </a>
  </tr>
</template>
```

Comment: it's invalid html - anchors cannot be a child of tr. also if your td parent is display contents, then the table alignment won't work either as td parent needs to be display table row.  The best you could do is have your link in a td and then use js to bind a click to the row that will click your link when the row is clicked

Comment: @Pete Thanks for your answer. Can you give me a snippet code that how it could be done?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17147821/how-to-make-a-whole-row-in-a-table-clickable-as-a-link#answer-33214588