# my javascript function is returning a blank page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, flask

for context, i need a table row to be clickable and direct to a certain html page. these are the codes i'm using:
ps: this code already functions, but it generates the page i want (vehicledetails) as an extension of the same page, but i wanted it to be a new tab. as it is, i've only managed to get  ablank new page. can someone help?

```
<tr class="clickable" data-href="javascript:post2('vehicledetails',{weighing_id: {{row['weighing_id']}}})"> 
</tr>
```

```
<script>

 var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('clickable');
 for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
     var element = elements[i];
     element.addEventListener('click', function() {
         var href = this.dataset.href;
         if (href) {
            window.open(href);
        }
    });
  }


</script>
```

```
<script language="javascript"> 
  function post2(path, params, method='POST') {
  
      var form_data = $(this).serialize();
      console.log(form_data)
      $.ajax({
              url: path, 
              type: method,      
              data: params,     
              cache: false,           
              success: function(data){                          
                  $("#result").html(data);                     
              }           
          });    
  };
</script>
```

Comment: The problem is that `post2()` is defined in the original page, but `window.open()` will try to call it in the new page. If you check the console, it will say that the function is not defined.

Comment: there is. this is what it says: Uncaught ReferenceError: post2 is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:1

Comment: Also, the new page doesn't jave jQuery loaded.

Comment: And when the AJAX call completes, where do you expect `$("#result").html(data)` to write to? There's no HTML with `id="result"` in the new tab.

Comment: What is`$(this).serialize()` supposed to do? There's no form.

Comment: Then instead of `window.open(href);` try with `document.location = href;`. Also, do you *really* need a TR? See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61589399/383904. I'm not sure how the two scripts from your question are related... Would they work together? Mind to share some more light on the expected result and what you initially was aiming to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your code opens a new blank page because the **data-href** attribute contains a JavaScript function call (**javascript:post2(...)**), and this function doesn't return a URL.

To open a new tab with the **vehicledetails** page, you can directly set the URL in the **data-href** attribute and then open it in your click event listener. Here's how you can modify your code:

```
<tr class="clickable" data-href="vehicledetails?weighing_id={{row['weighing_id']}}">
   <!-- Your table row content here -->
</tr>
<script>
   var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('clickable');
   for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
       var element = elements[i];
       element.addEventListener('click', function() {
           var href = this.dataset.href;
           if (href) {
               window.open(href, '_blank'); // Open in a new tab
           }
       });
   }
</script>
```

In this code:

- The **data-href** attribute directly contains the URL with the **weighing_id** parameter.
- In the event listener, **window.open(href, '_blank')** will open the URL in a new tab.

Now, when you click the table row, it should open a new tab with the **vehicledetails** page, passing the **weighing_id** as a parameter. Make sure to adjust the URL format as needed to match your application's routing structure.

Comment: that worked quite well. thank you!