# When filling a table with js, tag a does not give the desired result

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hey i try to filling my tablo from js file.
I want tr tags to be surrounded by the a tag.
but i get 2 problems with 2 codes.
firstly when i use that code

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  $("#liste").find('tbody')
  .append($('<a>')
  .attr('href',data[i][0])
.append($('<tr>')
    .append($('<td>')      
        .text(data[i][1]) )
        .append($('<td>')
            .text(data[i][3])
            )
    )
);
}
```

Although everything seems to be the way I want in my table codes, it looks as if there are no style codes.

second problem is when i use that codes

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  $('#liste').append('<a href="'+data[i][0]+'"><tr><td>'+data[i][1]+'</td><td>'+data[i][3]+'</td></tr></a>');}
```

everything is beautiful in the image and content. but my a tags have never even been added.

Comment: You can't put `a` tag between `table` and `tr` tags. In your case I would try to go with JavaScript `onclick` for `tr` tag. Alternatively, you can put the same `a` tag into each of `td` tags. There is an explanation of it here https://stackoverflow.com/a/4369275/2224394

Answer (score 1):

You might try to go with JavaScript `onclick` for `tr` tag:

```js
// Mock data
const data = [
  ['https://bbc.com', '1a', '1b', '1c'],
  ['https://bing.com', '2a', '2b', '2c']
];

// Allows redirect to specific URL
function openLink(url) {
  window.location = url;
}

// Pay attention, that the link tag was removed from
// original code, onclick for tr tag was added instead
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  $('#liste').append('<tr onclick="openLink(\''+data[i][0]+'\')"><td>'+data[i][1]+'</td><td>'+data[i][3]+'</td></tr>');
}
```

```css
/* Style tr with onclick attribute as link */
tr[onclick] {
  color: blue;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="liste"></table>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is invalid HTML. You can't put a `<a>` in between a `<tbody>` and a `<tr>`.You could include an anchor inside every `<td>`
and then use below style to highlight whole row

```
tr:hover { background-color: yellow }
td a { 
    display: block; 
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 16px; 
}
```

```js
const data = [
  ['https://bbc.com', '1a', '1b', '1c'],
  ['https://bing.com', '2a', '2b', '2c']
];
$(document).ready(function(){

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  $('#liste').find('tbody').append('<tr><td><a href="'+data[i][0]+'">'+data[i][1]+'</a></td><td><a href="'+data[i][0]+'">'+data[i][3]+'</a></td></tr>');
  }
})
```

```css
tr:hover { 
background-color: yellow; 
}
td a 
{    display: block; 
    padding: 16px; 
}
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id ='liste'>
<table>
<tbody></tbody>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```